# Windows Docker Containers not displaying on localhost receiving "Page Isn't Working"

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-for-windows

I've spun up a sample NGINX docker container on docker for windows and I'm unable to view it on localhost OR the IP addr for the container image.

I've spun the container up running this simple command:

```
docker run --detach --publish 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

And when I hit http://localhost via the browser; I receive "This page isn't working" "X.X.X.X Didn't Send any Data" (X being the IP address or Localhost)

I've also obtained the IP address running the below command:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" webserver
```

Same result when I directly use the IP address. 
I'm new to docker and docker for windows and I'm unsure why I'm unable to view this sample app.

I was following these instructions when I discovered my issue : https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Here's the docker version I'm currently running:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           18.09.2
API version:       1.39
Go version:        go1.10.8
Git commit:        6247962
Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          18.09.2
API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version:       go1.10.6
Git commit:       6247962
Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
Experimental:     true
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment so I'm posting here.

do you have a server set up on your local machine already?
if so change 80:80 -> 81:80 on your 'docker run' command.

```
$ docker run --detach --publish 81:80 --name webserver nginx
```

if not verify the containers build with the print out of docker run.

then also provide the output of:

```
$ sudo docker inspect webserver
```